# Need Help to query SQL Server Table using SAS Proc SQL for most recent record

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am trying to query a sql server table of transactional data using SAS Proc SQL syntax.

I am unable to get the query to pull the most recent record from each case based on the last update date field.

Any assistance on the proper syntax would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Elliott

max(date)
having clause
several others

I do not believe I can create a temp table on sql server as I do not have write capability to the server.

Comment: Try to use `subquery` to filter the data based on the maximum date for each case: `SELECT MAX(last_update_date)`

Answer (score 1):

How about something with a sub-query, like this:

```
select 
  a.* 
from 
  YourTable as a
inner join
  (
  select 
    groupingID
  , max (lastUpdateDate) as LUDT
  from 
    YourTable
  group by 
    groupingID
  ) as b
on 
  a.groupingID = b.groupingID
  and
  a.lastUpdateDate = b.LUDT
;
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the above query, I have tested but ran out of space I have tried to add a where clause for a date range, but that has also failed.  Do you have an example of where a where stmt would be placed, I have tried below the first from and that failed, then I tried below the second from and that failed also.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group` and `having`

Example:

```
create table want as
select * from transactions
group by case
having date = max(date)
```

You may get higher performance by forcing the heavy lifting to occur in the SQL Server

```
proc sql;
  connect to SQL ...
  create table want as 
  select * from connection to SQL
  (
    select * from transactions
    group by case
    having date = max(date)
  )
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestions but I have to put a date range because there are too many records to even just pull max on.  I have tried the query several times and it fails with out of space issue.

Comment: What kind of machine are you running SAS on? How powerful is your SQL Server?  Can you perform the query directly in SQL Server using a sql server client such as Toad or SSMS? You might want to use a SAS startup option to increase your SAS session memory size to 4 or more GB.  What is logged by `
proc options group=memory; run;` If you have daily transactions, add `where date > today()-2` before `group`

Comment: Did you try the pass-through version?

Comment: SAS 9.4 is running on a linux box and I only have read capability to the sql server and have no information about that server.  I am using a SAS pass through query to get the sql data.  I am Using  SAS Studio app

Comment: Add to the question the log messages you are seeing.